# DENSE_RANK ORDER BY NULL always return 1

Tags: oracle, null, sql-order-by, dense-rank

I find in PROD procedure code like:

```
select *
from (select "EMPNO",
    "SAL",
    "COMM",
    "DEPTNO",
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY null) AS drank
    from SCOTT."EMP"
    where deptno in (10,30))
where drank = 1
order by deptno
```

RESULT:

```
EMPNO   SAL      COMM  DEPTNO   DRANK
7934    1300     -     10       1
7839    5000     -     10       1
7782    2450     -     10       1
7844    1500     0     30       1
7900    950      -     30       1
7654    1250     1400  30       1
7499    1600     300   30       1
7698    2850     -     30       1
7521    1250     500   30       1
```

As result **drank** is always equal to 1. This is also true for:

> DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY null) AS drank
>
> DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY comm ORDER BY null) AS drank
>
> DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY null) AS drank
>
> DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY null ORDER BY null) AS drank

Is there any case when **drank** is not equal to 1 when there is *ORDER BY null* clause?

EDIT: I know **dense_rank** start with 1. Question is about values greater than 1.

Comment: `order by null` makes no sense to begin with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) says:

> Use the *`order_by_clause`* to specify how data is ordered within a partition. For all analytic functions you can order the values in a partition on multiple keys, each defined by a *`value_expr`* and each qualified by an ordering sequence.
>
> Within each function, you can specify multiple ordering expressions. Doing so is especially useful when using functions that rank values, because the second expression can resolve ties between identical values for the first expression.
>
> Whenever the *`order_by_clause`* results in identical values for multiple rows, the function behaves as follows:
>
> - `CUME_DIST`, `DENSE_RANK`, `NTILE`, `PERCENT_RANK`, and `RANK` return the same result for each of the rows.
> - ...

When you `order by null`, the *`order_by_clause`* results in identical values for <strike>multiple</strike> **all** rows (in the partition), so they all get the same result.

The [documentation for `dense_rank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/DENSE_RANK.html) also says:

> The ranks are consecutive integers beginning with 1.

So they get the same result, which has to be 1.

Comment: I edit my question! Actually ask about values greater than 1.